# Possible to convert PGP ed25519 signature into signify-compatible format?

Tags: signature, pgp, ed25519

Both PGP and Signify (or Minisign) are capable of generating ED25519 detached signatures. Is it possible to convert a PGP-generated ED25519 signature into a signify-compatible format?

Comment: The data signed by the signature probably contains some PGP formatting data, and Signify signatures are probably supposed to sign some Signify formatting data, so I wouldn't expect that you could convert an existing signature from one to the other.

Comment: It might be possible to reuse a private key between both programs, but reusing keys between programs or protocols that aren't built for it can sometimes leak critical data. A better path would be to just PGP sign a message containing your Signify public key.

Comment: Hmm.. that's true, I totally forgot that PGP adds the date and full PGP fingerprint into the data being signed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage main reason is because there are hardware devices like Nitrokey that are able to do ED25519 crypto on the chip using OpenPGP protocol, while there aren't any that can do the same for signify/minisign, so the private key has to be stored on the system disk.

Comment: What operations does the Nitrokey perform on behalf of the host computer?  Does it do all the OpenPGP formatting itself, or does it just do the private key operation and leave all the rest of the details of signature-making to the host?